# How do I find the source for bugs in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have been dealing with a bug in Sublime Text in js files for a while where anytime I write a comma or semi-colon, Sublime Text creates an autocomplete box with a specific number 62118. So anytime I hit enter it will autofill this useless number and I have to delete it.

More keystrokes = More anger, so I was wondering if

1. anyone has run into this
2. or if anyone might have an idea whats causing it
3. OR if anyone has a good general technique for finding bugs in Sublime Text

It seems to only happen in .js files but I could be wrong so help me out here please I'd love to keep the configuration I have.

Comment: Are you sure it's sublime doing this? It could be a plugin you have installed.

Comment: It's definitely possible.  Is the only way to take care of it to uninstall each one and check functionality after or can I debug Sublime in some way?

Answer (score 0):

There may be information in the Sublime console. To open the console go to `View > Show Console` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>).

Otherwise, uninstall your plugins one by one. While it probably isn't necessary, it would be a good idea to restart Sublime each time you uninstall, to make sure any caches the plugins create are cleared.

Finally, you can simply disable autocomplete by adding the following to your User Settings.

```
"auto_complete": false
```

Comment: @CadenAlbaugh You should mark this question correct then.